# First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty with Gamepost

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Recieve  this error in my Game page in Rails 4 
 ActionView::Template::Error (First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty):

**_Gamepost_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for (@gamepost) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "Compose new game sale..." %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

**Controller**

```
class GamepostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :signed_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy, :]
  before_action :correct_user,   only: :destroy


  def index
    @gamepost = current_user.gameposts.build
  end

  def create
    @gamepost = current_user.gameposts.build(gamepost_params)
    if @gamepost.save
      flash[:success] = "Game Sale created!"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      @gamefeed_items = []
      render 'static_pages/home'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @gamepost.destroy
    redirect_to root_url
  end

  private

    def gamepost_params
      params.require(:gamepost).permit(:content)
    end

    def correct_user
      @gamepost = current_user.gameposts.find_by(id: params[:id])
    rescue
      redirect_to root_url
    end
end
```

Have a similar example using microposts and its working fine no idea why this instance is not working
After the answer Vee provided,

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `any?' for nil:NilClass):
1: <% if @gamefeed_items.any? %>
2:   <ol class="gameposts">
3:     <%= render partial: 'shared/gamefeed_item', collection: @gamefeed_items %>
```

This shows up in same page

Comment: You need to define `@gamepost` in the controller action that renders that form.

Comment: If that's a question, then yes `@gamepost = Gamepost.new`.  You probably also want to add `:new` to the `signed_in_user` callback.

Comment: where do i put the @gamepost = Gamepost.new?  I seen it at def new and other places

Comment: Where else do you see it?  Can you update your question with the latest code you have? (for this controller of course)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following up in the comments in your question.

Looks like you are rendering that form from your `index` action.

```
class GamepostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :signed_in_user, only: [ :index, :create, :destroy]
  ...

  def index
    @gamepost = current_user.gameposts.build
  end

  ...
end
```

Note that, you also need to add `:index` and not `:new` in `before_action :signed_in_user`.  This is to ensure that the `current_user` becomes available in so that `current_user.gameposts.build` does not fail!